# Can not use keyboard input to a textbox control in Silverlight 3 when the application is in full screen mode

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-4.0, keyboard-events

It appears when I move the application into full-screen mode - I cannot enter text into a text box control. It seems that the keyboard events are being ignored. I have found an article here (http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/142460.aspx) documenting the same problem.

I also have read that in Silverlight 4 if an application is trusted then keyboard events will be captured. In the mean time is there anyway I can do this i.e. with Silverlight-3? From what I've seen no!

Or say in the future is there anyway to allow non-trusted applications to have keyboard events fire in full screen mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do this in SL3, and you will only be able to do this in SL4 in an out-of-the-browser, trusted application.

It is a security issue, so this will never be allowed.  If you could draw the whole screen, you could make the user think the machine look like it needed a password to be entered (for instance, their system password, or their google password).

Comment: Yeah I had a feeling it was a bit of a security issue!! In the end  the application was designed so that it came out of full screen automatically if certain actions were taken.